# Index of Hydrogen Deficiency for para-Toluenesulfonylchloride

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

In para-Toluenesulfonylchloride, there are 5 pi bonds and 1 ring. This suggests a IHD of 6. However, the actual IHD is 4. How come?

Is it because the formula IHD = rings + pi bonds does not apply to compounds containing sulfur? If not, what formula do I use? I have this formula:

$IHD = \frac{2C + N - X - H + 2}{2}$

Using this formula yields a IHD of 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to start from the general formula for the [degree of unsaturation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_unsaturation)
$$DU = 1 + \frac{1}{2} \sum n_i(v_i-2),$$
where $n_i$ is the number of atoms with a valency of $v_i$.

For para-toluenesulfunylchloride ($\ce{C7H7SO2Cl}$) you will therefore arrive at
\begin{align}DU &= 1 + \frac{1}{2}\Big[n_\ce{C}(4-2) + n_\ce{H}(1-2) + n_\ce{S}(6-2) + n_\ce{O}(2-2) + n_\ce{Cl}(1-2)\Big]\\
&=1+\frac12\Big[7(4-2) + 7(1-2) + 1(6-2) + 2(2-2) +1(1-2)\\
&=1 + \frac12\Big[14 -7 +4 +0 -1\Big]\\
&=6,
\end{align}

because sulfur uses all six valence electrons in this case.

Comment: Just to confirm though, you need to know the oxidation state of sulfur before using the equation.

Comment: @jerepierre Yes of course. I was just making the point that the OP used the wrong formula.

Answer (score 2):

There are 5 pi bonds: three C-C in the ring and two S-O pi bonds. Add the ring, and the IHD is 6.

Because of it's ability to exist as higher oxidation states than the second row elements, I don't believe that there is any way to include sulfur in the IHD formula unambiguously. Consider the following two compounds, toluenesulfonyl chloride and an isomer.

[image]

The formulas are the same, but the IHD of the left structure is 6 but the right structure is 4.

I think the best way to handle third row (and beyond) is to treat the large atom as if it were it's second row analog (P->N, S->O, etc.), and use the result as the lower limit on the IHD.