# Degree of Unsaturation or Index of Hydrogen Deficiency

Tags: organic-chemistry

I know the formula for the DOU, but don't really understand why the formula works. Could someone elaborate that to me?

Comment: Simple things first. Is it clear why $2n+2$ works in alkanes?

Comment: @IvanNeretin Yes.

Comment: The rest is simple. How many hydrogens do you need to remove to turn a single bond into double?

Comment: @IvanNeretin 2 hydrogens.

Comment: Well, that's it. What else is left to understand?

Comment: @IvanNeretin I figured out I was not able to accept it without the derivation, the answer on this question linked a derivation after reading which I can now fully comprehend why the formula is as it is.

Comment: The formula is unnecessary. You may convert the formula of a given compound into CxHy and calculate the difference between number of hydrogen CxH2x+2 and divide it by 2 to get DOU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula for calculating the Degree of Unsaturation (DU) is awkward. The derivation will come later. There is a better way to address this issue by what I shall call the Atom Replacement Method (ARM). The gist of the method is to replace all heteroatoms with C and/or H. This revised formula is compared with the most saturated hydrocarbon bearing the same number of carbon atoms. As an example, consider the molecular formula of the marine dye [Tyrian purple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyrian_purple): $\ce{C16H8Br2N2O2}$.

[image]

Replace halogens with the same number of hydrogens and ignore divalent atoms: $\ce{C16H8Br2N2O2}$ --> $\ce{C16H10N2}$
Replace each nitrogen with one carbon and one hydrogen: $\ce{C16H10N2}$ --> $\ce{C18H12}$ (**1**)
The most saturated $\ce{C18}$ hydrocarbon is $\ce{C18H38}$ (**2**)
Subtracting **1** from **2** gives 26.
DU=26/2=13. There are 4 rings and 9 double bonds in Tyrian purple.

The following derivation of the formula is located [here](http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/%7Echem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/unsaturation/unsat.html). Here is a synopsis.

Let c=#C, h=#H, n=#N and x=#Br, where "x" is the number of halogens.
Ignoring divalent atoms and replacing xX with xH in C<sub>c</sub>H<sub>h</sub>N<sub>n</sub>X<sub>x</sub>
gives C<sub>c</sub>H<sub>h+x</sub>N<sub>n</sub>
Replacing nN with nC and nH yields C<sub>c+n</sub>H<sub>h+x+n</sub> (**1**)
The most saturated hydrocarbon is C<sub>c+n</sub>H<sub>2(c+n)+2</sub> (**2**)
Subtracting **1** from **2** and simplifying gives 2c+2n+2-h-n-x
Further simplification affords 2c+n+2-h-x
Division by 2 gives
DU = c+1+(n-h-x)/2
Q.E.D.
For a related discussions on ChemSE, see [this link](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/136377/importance-of-halogens-and-nitrogen-in-degree-of-unsaturation/136384#136384) and [this one](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16046/index-of-hydrogen-deficiency-for-para-toluenesulfonylchloride?rq=1).

Comment: Aah! Got it after reading your answer and the derivation. Thank you so much!

Comment: This method is godly! No need to bend the brains.

Comment: @Laxmi Narayan Bhandari: This method may not work when N or S is at an oxidation state greater than -3 and -2, respectively. Compare nitrobenzene with aniline.

Comment: @user55119 so basically, for simple looking compounds right? with the usual covalent bonds, that is